# How to read different language files from using c#.net

Tags: c#, streamreader, filereader

We will be given different text files and each file might be in English,arabic,german or French.We have to read the respective files and display the text in UI in the respective file text language.

I am planning to use the below statement to achieve the same. Do I need to do anything in addition here? As far as I know we have ASCII character-set -255 but how about displaying other language characters like Chinese,hindi or german  ? Do we need to take special care of these characters?

```
StreamReader(System.String filepath, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
```

Comment: Please read [Absolute minimum on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by the Joel... May make things a bit more clear for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTF-8 or UTF-16 for the encoding, and the text should be displayed as is

```
StreamReader(System.String filepath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```